What to do when seeing Gradle demoted library version
In Android Studio, there is a warning message when I am updating libraries as shown in the screenshot


Gradle demoted library version from 2.8.6 to 2.8.5

What action should we take?

Leave it
Reverse it
In what situation Gradle demotes or promotes a libraries?


What other androidx libraries (full artifact coordinate including version) do you use in this project? May be gradle has demaoted the version to match the other libraries. Or you have included those libraries two times via dependencies. Have you checked your dependency tree? ./gradlew app:dependencies
